# Realex payment Integration getting error 508 Invalid characters in amount field.(PHP)

Tags: php, realex-payments-api

I integrated the Realex payment gateway. It's working only in the case that the payment amount is an integer, otherwise it's getting an error when the amount is a float value.  Are there any solutions?

Comment: Doesn't the API documentation explain this? It looks like fairly basic stuff for a payment gateway.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use integer amounts only. E.g.

```
9.99 EUR => 999
20c => 20
14.99 USD => 1499
```

Multiply your float amounts by 100 and convert to int.